# Using jQuery and a Button to Toggle Editable Field and Class Name (jQuery, HTML, PHP)

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build user profiles with editable fields.

My approach is to allow a field to be edited by clicking a button that says "edit".  On click, jQuery should

- Change the styling of the field to draw user's attention
- Allow the field to be editable
- Change the button text to "save"
- Change the button class to "save" in order to call new jQuery functionality on the subsequent click

When the button that says "save" is clicked, jQuery should

- Make the field non-editable
- Remove styling
- Update the DB via AJAX (not coded yet)
- Change class back to "edit"
- Change button text back to "edit"

My problem is that the "edit" jQuery code block executes and produces the desired results but the "save" code block doesn't work on click.

Dev tools show no errors.

https://jsfiddle.net/848yqkvz/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="row text-center company">Company Name</div>
<button class="btn btn-default edit">Edit</button>
```

**"edit button" JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.edit').click(function() {
    $('.company').attr('contenteditable', 'true').css({
      'border': 'black solid 1px',
      'outline': 'none'
    }).focus();
    $(this).text("Save").addClass('save').removeClass('edit');
  });
});
```

**"save button" JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.save').click(function() {
    alert("working!");
    $('.company').attr('contenteditable', 'false').css({
      'border': 'none',
      'outline': 'none'
    });
    $(this).text("Edit").addClass('edit').removeClass('save');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining two separate events for `edit` and `save`, you can combine them into single event and play with the class. Your code is adding a `save` class, you can use that as a condition and change the input field as well as save accordingly. Below is the working code:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('save')) {
    alert("Saved!!!");
    $(this).text("Edit").removeClass('save');
    $('.company').attr('contenteditable', 'false').css({
      'border': 'none',
      'outline': 'none'
    });
  } else {
    $(this).text("Save").addClass('save');
    $('.company').attr('contenteditable', 'true').css({
      'border': 'black solid 1px',
      'outline': 'none'
    }).focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row text-center company">Company Name</div>
<button class="btn btn-default edit">Edit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Milan, that worked perfectly.  That said, I'm not sure why my original code didn't work.  Logically, it makes sense but the second action won't run.

Anyway, thank you for your help.